# C the right way to free a struct

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, memory-management, memory-leaks

Let's imagine that you want to free a linked list node which happens to be a struct which is the right way to do it to prevent memory leaks
struct

```
struct node{
    int value;
    struct node *next;
};
```

my solutions:

```
free(node);
```

or

```
free(node->next);
free(node);
```

if none of these are correct please correct me with you answers
thanks :>

Comment: Everything you allocated with `malloc`, `calloc` or `realloc` needs to be free'd with `free`. With that said, doing `free(node->next)` is probably not a good idea.

Comment: @procoder35 Without the context the question does not make a sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have allocated memory using malloc, calloc and realloc free is the right way to free a strict.

These are dynamic memory allocation in C. So only if you have dynamically allocated memory using these operators then you can use the free.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how the data was allocated. If it was all allocated by `malloc` then yes, you need to free individual struct pointer members to such data before freeing the struct as whole, in several steps.